# Retrieve the last date of all the months

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an ordered list of dates as input.

I want to retrieve the last date of all the months as output as `Column F`. Does anyone know how to achieve this by **only one** formula ("Control + Shift + Enter" array formula, or dynamic array, or a list of identical formulas by copy-paste)?

PS: `Column D` is a so so output made by myself, it contains empty in the list.

[image]

Comment: I'm unable to understand,, relationship between **Retrieve the last date of all the months** and **23/02/2019** for **03/02/2019** !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **F2** , enter the ***Array Formula***:

```
=MAX(IF(MONTH($B$2:$B$27)=ROWS($1:1),$B$2:$B$27))
```

and copy downward.  Adjust range to match your data:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Comment: Are you sure it works?

Comment: @SoftTimur  Must be an array formula.  Sorry............

Comment: @SoftTimur  I fixed the answer.

Comment: Thank you... It works on my side too... I also write a formula `=IF(MAX(IF(MONTH($B$2:$B$27)=ROWS($1:4);$B$2:$B$27;0))=0;"";MAX(IF(MONTH($B$2:$B$27)=ROWS($1:4);$B$2:$B$27)))` to write `""` rather than `0` when there is no day in a month, do you happen to have a simpler way to do so?

Comment: @SoftTimur  Your way works and is easy to understand.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent,,, don't you think that Title of the  **Retrieve the last date of all the months** doesn't justifies  `23/02/2019` for `03/02/2019`,, since last date is `28/29` for `Feb`,, I'm little confused!!